# $(\mathbb{Z}/(p) - \{[0]\}, \times)$ is a group $\Longleftrightarrow p$ is a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

May I verify if my proof to the a/m claim is correct? Thank you.

Suppose $G = (\mathbb{Z}/(p) - \{[0]\}, \times)$ is a group. Given $[a] \in G, $ where $0 < a \leq p-1,$ $\exists! [b] \in G$ such that $[a]\times[b] = [ab] = [1],$ where $[1]$ is the identity of $G.$ It follows that $gcd(a,p)=1.$ Since $a$ is arbitrary, $p$ must be a prime.

Conversely, if  $p$ is a prime, take any $[a], [b] \in G = \mathbb{Z}-\{kp: k \in \mathbb{Z}\},$ where $0 < a,b \leq p-1. $

So, 
$gcd(a,p)=1 $ $ \wedge $ $gcd(b,p)= 1 $
$\implies gcd(ab,p)=1$
$ \implies [ab]  \in G.$

Take $[1]$ to be the identity of $G.$ Given $[c] \in G, \exists r,s \in \mathbb{Z}: pr+cs = 1$. Note that $s \neq 0.$ Since $G = \mathbb{Z}-\{kp: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, this means $s \in [s]= [d], $ for some $d \in \{1,...,p-1\},$ where $0 < d \leq p-1. $ Hence $[d] = $ inverse of $[c].$ Associativity clearly holds.

Comment: It does not follow from $\gcd(ab, p) = 1$ that $ab$ is the identity element (if that is what you mean by $[ab] = [1]$).

Comment: Interestingly, if $p$ is not a prime, the set $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ is not even closed under multiplication.